# Какое здесь сказуемое? Подскажите, пожалуйста. В этом предложении Это одно и то же

Tags: сказуемые

Какое здесь сказуемое? Подскажите, пожалуйста.
В этом предложении Это одно и то же.

Answer (score 2):

Это одно и то же.

Сказуемое - *одно и то же* (устойчивое выражение).

Смысл такой: это *одинаковые понятия*.